# While creating AWS CodePipeline using cloudformation as deploy option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, continuous-integration

I am using AWS console to create a pipeline and using AWS Cloudformation as deploy option and passing all parameters as default through CFT, it is throwing following error in deploy stage

```
Action execution failed
Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXX)
```

and I have given the public access to my bucket and also assigned admin access role to my pipeline still the issue is not get solved.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've ruled out permissions as a possible cause, another thing to be aware of is that S3 can return permission denied instead of a 404 to prevent disclosing whether an object exists or not to someone who might not have access.

I'd check that the bucket, object, etc. exist and if not you might find that to be the cause.

There's more details on this behavior here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=56531